# I cashed out coins to my send address instead of my receive address in multi bit wallet where are they? can I get to them?

Tags: transactions

I cashed out coins without thinking in bitcoin blackjack and pasted my send address. Its not showing up in my wallet. How do I get to these bitcoins? Thanks for you help.

Comment: What does "my send address" mean?

Comment: Maybe they went back to your blackjack account?

Comment: With MultiBit you might try reetting the blockchain and seeing if the problem persists.